# How do I get leaflet marker labels in R to show HTML AND include label for only location of marker

Tags: r, leaflet

I am showing multiline labels in leaflet markers. Each label combines several columns of data. If if I just paste the columns together, I get one location per marker but no HTML rendering (Example 1).  If I wrap the label with `HTML()` I get proper rendering but EVERY location is in each marker (Example 2).  How do I get the desired content AND the desired formatting?  Thanks.

```
library(htmltools)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

df <- read.csv(textConnection(
  "Name,Rating,Lat,Long
Samurai Noodle,Good, 47.597131,-122.327298
Kukai Ramen,Fair,47.6154,-122.327157
Tsukushinbo,Great,47.59987,-122.326726"))

# EXAMPLE 1. One location per marker but HTML not rendered
leaflet(df) %>%  
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(~Long, ~Lat,
             label = ~ paste(Name,Rating,sep = "<br/>"))

# EXAMPLE 2. HTML rendered but all locations in each marker
leaflet(df) %>%  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(~Long, ~Lat,
             label = ~ HTML(paste(Name,Rating,sep = "<br/>")))
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe there is an easier option. But one fix for your issue would be to use `lapply` to apply `HTML` on each element of your vector of labels which avoids that your labels are glued together:

```
library(htmltools)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

df <- read.csv(textConnection(
  "Name,Rating,Lat,Long
Samurai Noodle,Good, 47.597131,-122.327298
Kukai Ramen,Fair,47.6154,-122.327157
Tsukushinbo,Great,47.59987,-122.326726"
))

leaflet(df) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(~Long, ~Lat,
    label = ~lapply(paste(Name, Rating, sep = "<br>"), HTML)
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in my own app that was solved by creating a column in the data frame before generating the map that includes the desired formatting. Also, for reasons I don't understand, you then pass that label to `popup` rather than `label` in the call to `addMarkers()`. So...

```
df$marker <- with(df, sprintf("%s </br> %s", Name, Rating))

leaflet(df) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(~Long, ~Lat,
             popup = ~marker)
```

...gives what I think is the result you're looking for.